# SQL get corresponding data where min or max value

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, partitioning

Here is my data structure

| ID_group | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20/11/2022 | 3 |
| 1 | 19/11/2022 | 4 |
| 2 | 18/11/2022 | 42 |
| 2 | 19/11/2022 | 2 |
| 1 | 21/11/2022 | 2 |

I want to make a table in order to get my data in this format :

| ID_group | MaxPrice | MaxPriceDate | MinPrice | MinPriceDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 19/11/2022 | 3 | 20/11/2022 |
| 2 | 42 | 18/11/2022 | 2 | 19/11/2022 |

Here is what I have now :

```sql
select ID_group,
max(price) MaxPrice,
'' MaxPriceDate,
min(price) MinPrice,
'' MinPriceDate
from table
group by ID_group
```

Comment: Just replace those single quotes to `max(Date)` and `min(Date)` respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here, along with pivoting logic:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_group ORDER BY Price) rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_group ORDER BY Price DESC) rn2
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT
    ID_group,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN Price END) AS MaxPrice,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN "Date" END) AS MaxPriceDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN Price END) AS MinPrice,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN "Date" END) AS MinPriceDate
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID_group
ORDER BY ID_group;
```

Comment: Thanks, Il not used to this Over(Partition by syntax), big thanks